# Rebuilding a complex Gtk Menu

Tags: python, ubuntu, gtk, pygtk

I have a Ubuntu program that displays a complex Gtk Menu with up to 4 nesting levels and a total of well over 100 menu items (not elegant, I know). The menu items represent items in the database, and when this data changes, the menu needs to be rebuilt.

So I have a function that takes care of this:

```
def rebuild_asset_menu(self):
    self.asset_menu.set_submenu(self._menu_bases())
    GLib.idle_add(self.asset_menu.show_all)
```

`self.asset_menu` is the menu item to which the massive submenu is attached. `self._menu_bases()` builds the submenu structure and returns it.

The building of the menu structure runs really lovely when the program starts. But when the above code is called to update the submenu (essentially replacing it with a new submenu), the GUI becomes really slow and often the menu remains empty.

Is it simply because I have too many menu elements, or am I doing something wrong? Or is it Unity?

Comment: OFF-TOPIC Is your program open sourced on GitHub or somewhere?

Comment: How often is called `rebuild_asset_menu`? My bet is that either you're calling it too often, or it takes too much time to execute. You'd be better served if you were only be notified of what has changed and update that, instead of reconstructing the whole menu from scratch.

Comment: @theGtknerd yes, it is. https://github.com/nilgradisnik/coinprice-indicator
liberforce it is only executed once, at user initiative. But then it still fails.

Comment: I am running it here on Mint 18 Cinnamon with no lag time. Could you explain exactly how to produce your problem?

Comment: Ok, now I get it. Discover Assets triggers the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I modify your code to this:

```
def rebuild_asset_menu(self):
    print ("rebuild")
    self.asset_menu.set_submenu(self._menu_bases())
    print ("rebuild1")
    self.asset_menu.show_all()
    print ("rebuild2")
```

The program rebuilds the menu multiple times. This is your problem. I did not dig into the problem any further.